# Compiler Error message because type exists in two versions of DLL in GAC

Tags: asp.net, gac, episerver

I get this error message:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'EPiServer.Web.WebControls.LogGenerator' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EPiServer\5.2.375.236__8fe83dea738b45b7\EPiServer.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EPiServer\6.1.379.0__8fe83dea738b45b7\EPiServer.dll'

Source Error:



Line 387:           </div>
Line 388:       </form>
Line 389:       <EPiServer:LogGenerator ID="PixelImg" runat="server" />
Line 390:<script type="text/javascript">
Line 391:    var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");


Source File: c:\Prokom\inter.oppdal.kommune.no_CMS6R2Blank\templates\Oppdal\MasterPages\MasterPage.master    Line: 389
```

Part of web.config:

I need the second `bindingRedirect`, because that a dll of the project is using it.
Is it possible to solve the problem without removing files from GAC and without recompiling the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompiling wont help you and neither will moving the assemblies to your bin folder. You're trying to use two major versions of the CMS together which I would think not supported.

In EPiServer CMS 7 the LogGenerator API and controls have been deprecated I believe. I think you can safely remove that particular line altogether. You can use Google Analytics or something else to gather statistics.

You're going to get into even more trouble later. Why are you using both versions? Maybe SO can solve that problem for you.

Comment: Thanks.
After writing the post I removed all binaries that referenced to an old EPiServer, recompiled the project with a newer EPiServer and removed the references in web.config for EPiServer 5. That solved the problem.